# unserialize(): Error at offset 9 of 13 bytes

Tags: php, arrays

I am getting this error? What does it mean?

```
 unserialize(): Error at offset 9 of 13 bytes
```

This is what I get after I serialize and store the array in database:

```
a:3:{i:0;s:6:
```

And at the time of unserialize, it gives the error! What should I do? 
I want my original array back and want to display it.

I have tried other post, like basencoder/decode, but thats not working too..

Create1.php(passing serialized array to next page through hidden input)

```
<form action="create2.php" method="POST">
<table cellpadding="10">
<tr>
  <td>Name</td>
  <td><input type="text" name="name" value="<?php echo $name; ?>" readonly="readonly" ></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Mobile</td>
  <td><input type="text" name="mobile" value="<?php echo $mobile; ?>" readonly="readonly" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Email</td>
  <td><input type="text" name="email" value="<?php echo $email; ?>" readonly="readonly" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Company</td>
  <td><input type="text" name="company" value="<?php echo $company; ?>" readonly="readonly" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <input type="hidden" name="original_list" value="<?php echo serialize($original_list); ?>"  />
  <input type="hidden" name="xerox_list" value="<?php echo serialize($xerox_list); ?>" />
</tr>
<tr>
  <td><input type="submit" value="Confirm" /></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
```

Create2.php(getting and storing serialized array in database)

```
$name = $_POST['name'];
$mobile = $_POST['mobile'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$company = $_POST['company'];
$original = $_POST['original_list'];
$xerox = $_POST['xerox_list'];


echo $sql = "INSERT INTO users (name,mobile,email,company,original,xerox)
VALUES ('$name','$mobile','$email','$company','$original','$xerox')";
mysqli_query($con,$sql);
```

Comment: That's not a valid serialized string. It's truncated.

Comment: Do you have a length limit on the database column?

Comment: Also, in [the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) it states: *Note that this is a binary string which may include null bytes, and needs to be stored and handled as such. For example, serialize() output should generally be stored in a BLOB field in a database, rather than a CHAR or TEXT field.*

Comment: Yes the string is getting trimmed. I have used varchar 100, which then I increased to 5000, still its getting trimmed. 
What else can i do to avoid it? Is it happening is my php code or in database?

Comment: @apokryfos so should I used BLOG instead of varchar? is that the issue?

Comment: Very likely you need to use BLOB instead of varchar. Also share the code that you use to store the serialised string if this doesn't work.

Comment: sidenote: It's BLOB. BLOG is something different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure it's safe to use binary strings in HTML (HTTP is a text protocol after all). I suggest using JSON encoding instead of serialization.

```
<input type="hidden" name="original_list" value="<?php echo json_encode($original_list); ?>"  />
 <input type="hidden" name="xerox_list" value="<?php echo json_encode($xerox_list); ?>" />
```

When accessing the entries you can then do:

```
json_decode($row['original'],true); //you get the idea
```

Comment: Your answer is right! Other users who are suffering from the same issue, Either use baseencoder/decoder or JSON encode/decode. And it works fine :)